# Trying to terminate the text drawn by drawText(Win32) if there is not enough height in the rect

Tags: c++, windows, win32gui, drawtext

I am trying to draw a multiline text using drawText.
I am able to keep the width constant by passing DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS | DT_WORDBREAK flags
but if the string is long the text is getting cut vertically in the last line.

How to ensure that drawText doesn't draw the last line if it it can't fit the whole height ?

Currently I am passing these flags to drawText - DT_NOPREFIX | DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS | DT_LEFT | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_EXTERNALLEADING

Comment: Yes I have tried putting that flag also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `DT_EDITCONTROL` flag.  According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498.aspx) documentation:

> **DT_EDITCONTROL**
>
> Duplicates the text-displaying characteristics of a multiline edit
>   control. Specifically, the average character width is calculated in
>   the same manner as for an edit control, **and the function does not
>   display a partially visible last line**.